# Distance calculator in PHP?

Tags: php

I have this simple piece of code for distance calculator and I found it [HERE](http://www.web-max.ca/PHP/misc_2.php).

However, I don't know why when i upload it to my server it doesn't work at all!

This is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
<html>
<body>
<?php

    $distances = array();
    $distances[0] = array("id"=>"0","name"=>"Pittsburgh","long"=>"-79.9954","lat"=>"40.4409");
    $distances[1] = array("id"=>"1","name"=>"Las Vegas","long"=>"-94.1024","lat"=>"36.1749");
    $distances[2] = array("id"=>"2","name"=>"Beaumont","long"=>"-79.9954","lat"=>"30.0862");
    $distances[3] = array("id"=>"3","name"=>"South Bend","long"=>"-86.2517","lat"=>"41.673");
    $distances[4] = array("id"=>"4","name"=>"Hampton","long"=>"-76.3447","lat"=>"37.03");
    $distances[5] = array("id"=>"5","name"=>"Savannah","long"=>"-81.0946","lat"=>"32.0728");


    if(getenv("REQUEST_METHOD")=="POST")
    {

        $lon1 = $distances[$from]["long"];
        $lat1 = $distances[$from]["lat"];

        $lon2 = $distances[$to]["long"];
        $lat2 = $distances[$to]["lat"];

        $distance = (3958*3.1415926*sqrt(($lat2-$lat1)*($lat2-$lat1) + cos($lat2/57.29578)*cos($lat1/57.29578)*($lon2-$lon1)*($lon2-$lon1))/180);

        $summary = "Total distance between ".$distances[$from]["name"]." and ".$distances[$to]["name"]." is ".sprintf("%01.02d",$distance)." km";
        $summary.= "<br><br>( $lon1,$lat1 )  ($lon2,$lat2)";
    }

?>
<table width="400" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
  <tr>
    <td><form name="form1" method="post" action="">
      <table width="400" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="bodytext">
        <tr>
          <td width="166"><select name="from" class="bodytext">
<?php foreach ($distances as $value){?>
<option <?php if($from==$value["id"])print("selected");?> value="<?php print($value["id"]);?>"><?php print($value["name"]);?></option>
<?php }?>
 </select></td>
          <td width="117"><select name="to" class="bodytext">
<?php foreach ($distances as $value){?>
<option <?php if($to==$value["id"])print("selected");?> value="<?php print($value["id"]);?>"><?php print($value["name"]);?></option>
<?php }?>
 </select></td>
          <td width="117"><input name="Submit" type="submit" class="bodytext" value="Calculate"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td colspan="3">
<?php   print($summary); ?></td>
          </tr>
      </table>
    </form></td>
  </tr>
</table>
</body></html>
```

am I missing something? I have updated the code now. the last code was wrong. sorry about that.

Comment: what is `$from` and `$to`?

Comment: `$from` one location `$to` another location. the thing is on that site where this was posted there is no documentation or explanation about this code.

Comment: first off, change your array to have int's instead of strings, as in the example. Also, why not use `if(isset($_POST["name_of_submit_button"]){ ` instead of what you have? Since you aren't getting _anything_, this might be the issue.

Comment: @arbitter, I haven't made any changes to the code whatsoever. I simply downloaded it from the link i posted here and uploaded it on my server as i was gonna test it. and Unfortunately nothing works when infact the same code seems to work fine on that site!

Comment: I just take your code and create my own file. Look [here](http://www.seo035.com/test/distance.php). It works fine and I changed nothing.

Comment: @FabienTheSolution, what version of PHP are you running on your server? all i get is this: `Total distance between and is 0 km

( , ) (,)`

Comment: It is not working since the `$to` and `$from` are not defined. Read errors.

Comment: It's PHP Version 5.2.17...just add a `phpinfo()` at the bottom of the script

Comment: Try running this on a local development machine, and turn on error display and warnings. I suspect there is a problem, but your remote server is not showing you what it is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is how you are taking values from form after it is submitted. You should do it by getting values of `$_POST` array, not from variables with names of your form components. This:

```
if(getenv("REQUEST_METHOD")=="POST")
{

    $lon1 = $distances[$from]["long"];
    $lat1 = $distances[$from]["lat"];

    $lon2 = $distances[$to]["long"];
    $lat2 = $distances[$to]["lat"];

    $distance = (3958*3.1415926*sqrt(($lat2-$lat1)*($lat2-$lat1) + cos($lat2/57.29578)*cos($lat1/57.29578)*($lon2-$lon1)*($lon2-$lon1))/180);

    $summary = "Total distance between ".$distances[$from]["name"]." and ".$distances[$to]["name"]." is ".sprintf("%01.02d",$distance)." km";
    $summary.= "<br><br>( $lon1,$lat1 )  ($lon2,$lat2)";
}
```

Should be turned into this:

```
if(getenv("REQUEST_METHOD")=="POST")
{
    $lon1 = $distances[$_POST["from"]]["long"];
    $lat1 = $distances[$_POST["from"]]["lat"];

    $lon2 = $distances[$_POST["to"]]["long"];
    $lat2 = $distances[$_POST["to"]]["lat"];

    $distance = (3958*3.1415926*sqrt(($lat2-$lat1)*($lat2-$lat1) + cos($lat2/57.29578)*cos($lat1/57.29578)*($lon2-$lon1)*($lon2-$lon1))/180);

    $summary = "Total distance between ".$distances[$from]["name"]." and ".$distances[$to]["name"]." is ".sprintf("%01.02d",$distance)." km";
    $summary.= "<br><br>( $lon1,$lat1 )  ($lon2,$lat2)";
}
```

Comment: & also change the `$from` and `$to` in the `foreach()` loops, and also in these loops check whether they are set or not to prevent bazillion errors.

Comment: that worked perfectly. but is that because i was running PHP 3 on my server?

Comment: also, this way only echo's `Total distance between and is 715 km`. there is no name of the locations for some reason!

Comment: I did try that before my post mate and it didn't work!

Comment: going to accept this as the answer but I would love to know why the the original code works on some servers and doesn't on others.

Comment: @FabienTheSolution, my server is running php 5.3 mate.

Comment: @EnergyLynxEnergyLynx Replace every `$from` with `$_POST["from"]`, do the same with `$to`. It does not work because on some servers of [register_globals](http://php.net/manual/en/security.globals.php) configuration. Please take a note that you should spend some time to learn language, how it works and understand what the code does on every line. Running scripts just copied from Internet is inviting trouble.